# Tarjan's strongly-connected components algorithm - why index in the back edge?

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic, directed-graph, tarjans-algorithm

I'm studying [Tarjan's algorithm for strongly-connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) and the way it works is clear to me. Anyway there's a line I don't understand:

```
// Consider successors of v
for each (v, w) in E do
  if (w.index is undefined) then
    // Successor w has not yet been visited; recurse on it
    strongconnect(w)
    v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)
  else if (w.onStack) then
    // Successor w is in stack S and hence in the current SCC
    v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.index) // *************
  end if
end for
```

I marked the line with asterisks. Why should we take the discovery index/time of a node when encountering a back-edge

```
v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.index)
```

rather than just grabbing its component value?

```
v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)
```

I can't think of a case where this would be a problem.

Can someone enlighten me please?
Edit: I *suspect* this is only a semantic requirement, i.e. lowlink being defined as the earliest ancestor reachable from the node with **only one back-edge**, but this is just a wild guess.

Comment: Tarjan came up with tons of elegant algorithms.  I hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: Oh absolutely not. Sorry for not specifying it in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114178/tarjans-algorithm-time-complexity-and-slight-modification-possibility/24114310#24114310)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correctness proof goes through if `w.lowlink` is at least the lowest index reachable from `w` and at most the lowest index reachable from `w` using at most one back edge. Component detection just requires us to know if we can "escape" to a lower index.

Probably the reason that it's presented the way that it is is that one can imagine `lowlink` only being set in post-order, and then your variation wouldn't be well defined. (The Wikipedia pseudocode initializes it in pre-order to `index`.)

Comment: OMG thank you! I was cracking my head trying to figure out why it wouldn't work. Good to know it does work!